# Error while opening a modal in angular

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-bootstrap

I am trying the example of modal given in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap. When i click the button  for an action, my screen gets blur as if some window popped up but I dont see anything out there and the console says this when i open a modal

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with the status 404 (Not Found)      ---         Cannot GET /function%20(a,b)%7Breturn%20b.templateUrl%7C%7C%22template/modal/window.html%22%7D
>   Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function    ---                       angular.min.js

My controller

```
'use strict'
var LoginCtrl = ['$scope', '$modal', '$log', function($scope, $modal, $log) {
  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
}];

var ModalInstanceCtrl = ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'items', function($scope, $modalInstance, items){
    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.selected = {
      item: $scope.items[0]
    };

    $scope.ok = function () {
      $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };

    $scope.cancel = function () {
      $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}];
```

My template

```
<div>
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
            <div>
                <h3 class="modal-title">I m a modal</h3>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                        <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
            </div>
            <div>
                <button ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                <button ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </script>

        <button ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
        <button ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
        <button ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
        <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
    </div>
```

Why I am seeing this strange error. I am loading ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js of version 0.11.2 and angular.min.js of version 1.3.1. I referred the same kind of issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647777/404-not-found-error-when-opening-modal-in-angular-ui-boostrap) and as said by one of them I have the updated versions too. Any suggestions would be a great help thanks.

Comment: Why not loading the template as a plain HTML, that is referencing the full .tpl file path (on templateUrl attribute) rather than using the angular definition of template (<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">)? Regardless, I would replace the templateUrl with basic template such as "<h1>Test</h1>" just to see what happens.

Comment: @Tomer: I replaced the templateUrl to '<h1>Test</h1>' and keeping rest the same. I still get Failed to load the resource error. Is that the same that you wanted me to check with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this looks like some loading order / mixing different version or dependency - issue(s).

 However, as it turned out it is the version of angular (1.1.3) that don't play nice with this version of bootstrap. 

So first, [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Wt4LiQvBfPNXwpZBdtw?p=preview) is a working version of your code (the main part), with angular 1.2.25. 
I've also included on the index.html, version 1.1.3 of angular (currently marked out). If you replace the two version, the error reproduces:

```
<!-- <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.3/angular.min.js"></script> -->
```

Regardless specific errors, I strongly recommend upgrading angular to version 1.3 (or 1.2.25 incase IE8 support is a must). It is by far faster, includes much more cool features and leverages many EMCA5 and HTML5 / CSS3 Capabilities.
Can't upgrade? Well it is debugging time... No you know what is wrong, "just" have to find why.
Good Luck!

Comment: I have double checked again once when I replied you early today and it was purely the version mismatch. The angular.js that I was referring too was somehow pointing to the older angular version. Thanks for you time and with clear working example of this. Glad that it worked.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you please mark the question as answered so it won't bother anymore..

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem and finally this [answer](http://www.epigroove.com/blog/solve-the-ui-bootstrap-modal-error-failed-to-load-template) saved my day.

Make sure you're linking to the UI Bootstrap library with the templates included (i.e. ui-bootstrap-tpls.js) and not the plain UI Bootstrap library (i.e. ui-bootstrap.js).

```
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js"></script>
```